# How to get kerbals out of Mobile Processing Lab MPL-LG-2?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have a space station on Duna orbit, equipped with [Mobile Processing Lab MPL-LG-2](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Mobile_Processing_Lab_MPL-LG-2). I plan to decommission it and bring my kerbals back (or move them to the new station). But I have no idea how to make them go EVA. Only pilots are listed in the right down corner of my screen (one for station, 2 for rescue vehicles). Is there any way to do it, without hacking saves or using Crew Manifest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you left click on the hatch, it'll bring up a list of occupants with an EVA button next to each of their names.  Then it's just a simple matter of flying them to wherever they need to be.  This is the same process that you use for the stock hitchhiker pod as well.

Comment: Never used stock hitchhiker pod so far - never seen a point. Lab is first part that gives a real *reason* to keep kerbals in not-a-pod. I guess that explains how I managed to advance in game without knowing that :D Will accept when I'll run the game next time (if it'll work). Does it matter which hatch I click?

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I left/right/middle/whatever click the hatch and nothing happens.

Comment: @MarcHughes: The only thing I can say is that you're doing it wrong.  When you hover over the hatch, it should say "Crew Hatch", and that's when you should left click.  That's the same with everything.  I mean, maybe it's because my hitch hiker pod is modded, but I'm pretty sure I've seen the same behaviour from before installing said mod.

Comment: I do see the "Crew Hatch" tooltip piece, and that is when I left click.  But nothing happens.

Comment: @MarcHughes: I don't know what to say, it should be working for you.  There must be something different with your setup.  Unless you're trying to click on the tooltip.  You're not doing that, are you?

Comment: @MarcHughes are you on a Mac, perchance? Apparently there's a bug in that version that I was unaware of.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, and have run into that before, where I can't use the Crew Hatch dialog to get at the occupants. But if I hover over the astronaut's faces in the lower-right, there's an EVA button there for each one individually. That works in all the pods I use; not sure if it will also work for the Lab?

Comment: @MidnightLightning with the stock game (unless there's something I missed in the latest version), those don't show up for either the mobile lab or the hitchhiker pod.  If they did, I doubt the OP would have posted the question.

Answer (score -2):

If it doesn't work for you, the module is empty.  There are no Kerbals inside.